# Multiple Background colors at print preview

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to print a bootstrap modal with dynamically generated table in it. The table contains a 'td' for 'rating', background color of 'td' varies based on rating as below.

3 - Green, 2 - Yellow, 1 - Red.

Background colors are getting displayed on bootstrap modal properly. When user clicks 'Print' button on the modal, modal without colors is displayed in print preview.

Even after trying browser print settings, this is still happening.

What's the better way to show colors in print preview mode?

Below is my CSS Code:

```
@media print{

    #modal-Printbtn,#modal-Closebtn{
        display:none;
    }
    #stp-modalViewHeaderContent{
        display:none;
    }
    #stp-printViewHeaderContent{
        display:block !important;
    }
    /*Hiding Metric Table For More Space In Header*/
    #printMetricTbl{
        display:none;
    }
    /* on modal open bootstrap adds class "modal-open" to body, so you can handle that case and hide body */
    body.modal-open {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    body.modal-open .modal .modal-header,
    body.modal-open .modal .modal-body {
        visibility: visible;  /* make visible modal body and header */
    }

    body.modal-open .modal {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: visible!important;
    }       
}
```

This is how, i'm coloring background of 'td' through code,

```
      var ratingSelected = $tds.eq(1).find('option:selected').text();
      var rating,bgColor;

      if(ratingSelected == 'Select'){
            rating = '';
            bgColor = returnPrntDynaColorCode(rating);
      }
      else{
            rating = ratingSelected;
            bgColor = returnPrntDynaColorCode(rating);              
      }
```

Function returns color based of 'rating',

```
      function returnPrntDynaColorCode(metricVal){
           if (metricVal == '3'){
             return '#74fe36'   
           }
      else if (metricVal == '2'){
             return'#ffff00';
           }
      else if (metricVal == '1'){
             return '#ff0000';
           }
      else if (metricVal == 0){
             return 'transparent';
           }
      }
```

Coloring background as below,

```
<td style='background-color:"+bgColor+";text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;'>" rating </td>;
```

How can i implement, dynamic color coding based of rating at print preview?

For better understanding, I'm providing images

[Rating Displayed in UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvYy2.jpg)

[Rating Displayed in Print Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5IYj.jpg)

Note : Font in print preview is small, because of custom CSS.

Comment: Where's your code? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry about that. Here you go,

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on browser implementation, but for Chrome you can try adding "-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;" to get the colors on print mode.

You shouldn't forget to add that property on the @media print and always be selective of the styles you add for print-only settings.

For example:

You can check [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lucaslazaro/eagdppub/1/) or the result for [easier print verification](https://jsfiddle.net/lucaslazaro/eagdppub/1/embedded/result/)

But it would go like this:

HTMl:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Head</th>      
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Rating</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen {
  td {
    background-color: red;
  }
}

@media print {
  td {
    background-color: blue;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Below is my CSS @ print

Comment: @media print{
    body.modal-open {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    body.modal-open .modal .modal-header,
    body.modal-open .modal .modal-body {
        visibility: visible;  /* make visible modal body and header */
    }
    
    body.modal-open .modal {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: visible!important;
    }       
}

Comment: @Naju I've added an example with the use of the `-webkit-print-color-adjust` I've mentioned.

Comment: I have updated my question, the thing is table has 42 rows, row 1  - td rating 3 - color : green, row 2 - td rating 2 - color : yellow, row 3 and so on... The color coding is not static, it varies based on rating.

Comment: @Naju I understand, but have you tried adding the aforementioned fix to your @ media print css?

Comment: as i'm not assigning colors manually for each 'td' in modal, tried like this,

Comment: @Naju What I meant was that the fix to add `-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;` is independent of the way you assign the colors, but perhaps what you should do is: instead of applying color directly with your function, you could apply a class to it, that class would contain the color, then it will provide the visual aspect you need on print.

Comment: I missed code in previous comment, I added a class for 'td', #ModalTbl tbody tr > td.modal-metricRating{
  -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
 }